# How to rotate MapView in MapBox GL?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I want to rotate my activity with MapView without configuration change, relying on sensors. So I need to somehow set rotation to whole map wiew, so compass and watermark will be placed correctly. But after `mapView.rotation(angle)` it became stretched and glitchy. Is there any way to make it gracefully? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `MapView` will use a SurfaceView, this kind of transformation is only supported using TextureView as rendering surface. To enable this, you either set this up with xml attrs as `mapbox_renderTextureMode=true` or by using `MapboxMapOptions#textureMode(true)` programatically.